# How to convert to Pandas datetime to date to integer in pandas?

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe, integer, days

How can I convert in `pandas` a date format that looks something like this:

```
2018-08-27 00:00:00.000
2018-08-26 00:00:00.000
2018-08-24 00:00:00.000
2018-08-24 00:00:00.000
2018-08-24 00:00:00.000
2018-08-24 00:00:00.000
2018-08-23 00:00:00.000
2018-08-23 00:00:00.000
2018-08-20 00:00:00.000
2018-08-20 00:00:00.000
```

to an integer format counting the days since first of January 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract date from column by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) and convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df['days'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).sub(pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01')).dt.days
print (df)
                      date  days
0  2018-08-27 00:00:00.000  3160
1  2018-08-26 00:00:00.000  3159
2  2018-08-24 00:00:00.000  3157
3  2018-08-24 00:00:00.000  3157
4  2018-08-24 00:00:00.000  3157
5  2018-08-24 00:00:00.000  3157
6  2018-08-23 00:00:00.000  3156
7  2018-08-23 00:00:00.000  3156
8  2018-08-20 00:00:00.000  3153
9  2018-08-20 00:00:00.000  3153
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply apply sub on the pandas Timestamp column like this as mentioned by jezrael in his answer which is very direct.

If you want to do the same serially one by one you can do it like this with the help of map

```
base_date = pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00')

df['days'] = df['date'].map(lambda date : (pd.Timestamp(date) - base_date).days )
```

Comment: You forgot to convert the Date column.